# delete tables between some values

Tags: php, mysql, xml, feed

I have created PHP script which will create new table everyday. In the table we have product feed with current timestamp.

So, now after some days I will have many tables with values of different datatime. I want to remove some tables which contains datetime between some period of time like between value X and Y, (X is for example '2017-01-06' and Y is '2017-01-13').

Is it possible. How can I achieve this with single query?

Comment: You would need do run a loop for all the dates between X and Y and execute drop table command if you ever want to do it. But running Drop table command  for mass tables is always a bad idea though.

Comment: And the answer is: Yes of course you can.

Comment: You can do it, but you shouldn't. It would be probably better to save all the data in one table, with one column for date. You would then be able to delete all old rows with just one query.

Comment: I just need to find a way to delete tables where the creation date is between two values.

Comment: How would you do it  in phpMyAdmin for example. So automate that process, thats what developers do!

Comment: If you are using a linux machine, you can always run cron job to automate the process.

Comment: To recap. This is a terrible idea.

Comment: Really bad idea to be creating tables like that. Do as @Jiri Hrazdil suggests. Otherwise, why bother with a RDMS?